# Multiple parent activity

Tags: android, navigation, back

I have an address picker activity that is used from multiple activities to pick an address... but I can only specify one parent activity for my picker. Is there anyway to set multiple parent activities for a single activity?

Answer (score -1):

If you mean that manifest attribute, it only states which activity you go to when you press back button. There's no point for several activities in this case.

In no way it restricts you from going to this activity from another one in your app.

Comment: But if I dont set the parent activity android dont update the styles of the action bar for example.

Comment: @DanielG.R. could you please elaborate your idea a little bit? Styles are generally defined by the app theme and styles.